# SQL Pivot problems

Tags: sql

I have a view called vwLocations that contains addresses for a person

columns are personid, address1, address2, city, state, zip

i person can have 1 to many addresses

I need to pull this in a dynamic pivot but i am struggling:

results should be

personid, aadr1 Address1, aadr1Address2, aadr1City, addr1State, addr2Zip, addr2Address1, addr2Address2, addr2City, addr2State...addrNAddres1, addrNAddress2, addrNCity, addrNState

EDIT:

| PersonID | Address1 | Address2 | City | State | Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 1 | 456 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 1 | 789 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 2 | 123 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 2 | 456 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 2 | 789 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 3 | 123 main st |  | Home | CA | 90210 |

given that input i would need the following output

| PersonID | Addr1Address1 | Addr1Address2 | Addr1City | Addr1State | Addr1Zip | Addr2Address1 | Addr2Address2 | Addr2City | Addr2State | Addr2Zip | Addr3Address1 | Addr3Address2 | Addr3City | Addr3State | Addr3Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 | 456 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 | 789 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 2 | 123 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 | 456 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 | 789 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 |
| 3 | 123 Main St |  | Home | CA | 90210 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: you have to provide sample data and desired output

Comment: thanks, i have edited the question with data examples

Comment: also tag your database

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server:

```
 create table vwLocations (PersonID int,    Address1 varchar(100),  Address2 varchar(100),  City varchar(100), State varchar(100),  Zip int);
 
 
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(1,  '123 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(1,  '456 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(1,  '789 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(2,  '123 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(2,  '456 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(2,  '789 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
 insert into vwLocations (PersonID ,    Address1,City,State,Zip) values(3,  '123 main st',      'Home', 'CA',   90210);
```

Query:

```
 DECLARE @colAddress1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @colAddress2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @colCity  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @colState  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @colZip  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @coltoshowAddress1 AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @coltoshowAddress2  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @coltoshowCity  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @coltoshowState  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @coltoshowZip  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
     @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
     
     
 with cte as 
 (
 select distinct concat('Addr',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),'Address1')NewAddress1,
 concat('Addr',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),'Address2')NewAddress2,
 concat('Addr',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),'City')NewCity, 
 concat('Addr',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),'State')NewState,
 concat('Addr',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),'Zip')NewZip
 from vwLocations
 )
 select  @colAddress1 =string_agg( newaddress1,','),
         @colAddress2 =string_agg( newaddress2,','),
         @colCity =string_agg( newCity,','),
         @colState =string_agg( newState,','),
         @colZip =string_agg( newZip,','),
         @coltoshowAddress1 =string_agg( Concat('Max(',newaddress1,')',newaddress1),','),
         @coltoshowAddress2 =string_agg( Concat('Max(',newaddress2,')',newaddress2),','),
         @coltoshowCity =string_agg( Concat('Max(',newCity,')',newCity),','),
         @coltoshowState =string_agg( Concat('Max(',newState,')',newState),','),
         @coltoshowZip =string_agg( Concat('Max(',newZip,')',newZip),',')
 from cte
 
 
 set @query = 'SELECT PersonId,' +concat(@coltoshowAddress1 ,',', @coltoshowAddress2 ,',', @coltoshowCity ,',', @coltoshowState ,',', @coltoshowZip) + '
              from 
              (
                 select *,concat(''Addr'',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),''Address1'')NewAddress1,
 concat(''Addr'',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),''Address2'')NewAddress2,
 concat(''Addr'',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),''City'')NewCity, 
 concat(''Addr'',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),''State'')NewState,
 concat(''Addr'',row_number()over(partition by PersonId order by Address1),''Zip'')NewZip
 from vwLocations
             ) x
            pivot
             (
               max(Address1) for NewAddress1 in ('+@colAddress1+')
             )pivAddress1
            pivot
             (
               max(Address2) for NewAddress2 in ('+@colAddress2+')
             )pivAddress2
            pivot
             (
               max(City) for newCity in ('+@colCity+')
             )pivCity
            pivot
             (
               max(State) for NewState in ('+@colState+')
             )pivState
            pivot
             (
               max(Zip) for NewZip in ('+@colZip+')
             )pivZip
 Group by PersonID'
 
            
 execute(@query)
```

Output:

| PersonId | Addr1Address1 | Addr2Address1 | Addr3Address1 | Addr1Address2 | Addr2Address2 | Addr3Address2 | Addr1City | Addr2City | Addr3City | Addr1State | Addr2State | Addr3State | Addr1Zip | Addr2Zip | Addr3Zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 main st | 456 main st | 789 main st | null | null | null | Home | Home | Home | CA | CA | CA | 90210 | 90210 | 90210 |
| 2 | 123 main st | 456 main st | 789 main st | null | null | null | Home | Home | Home | CA | CA | CA | 90210 | 90210 | 90210 |
| 3 | 123 main st | null | null | null | null | null | Home | null | null | CA | null | null | 90210 | null | null |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3e64fda49b2b2f39fa4a269efa310e15)*